# How to set type for Vue.js filter and method parameters?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do I declare types for component method and filter parameters in Vue.js? I keep getting errors like the following:

```
client:167 (undefined) [at-loader] ./src/components/rating-tile/RatingTile.ts:37:42 
 TS7006: Parameter 'iconStyle' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

For reference, here's the filter that throws that error:

```
Vue.filter('getIconPath', function (str, iconStyle) {
    return require('./assets/' + str + iconStyle + '.png') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add type annotations to the parameters, for example:

```
Vue.filter('getIconPath', function (str: string, iconStyle: string) {
    return require('./assets/' + str + iconStyle + '.png') 
});
```

See the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types).